# stageroscam, using stage, and rviz

Tags: simulation, rviz, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

received the folowing error using command roslaunch IGVC2013_AutoNavBasic.launch which is supposed to launch roscore, stage environment and rviz. instead only rviz opens and the following error is displayed.

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [stage_ros/stageros]: stage_ros
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/amrl/ros/stageroscam
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
e
I am new at using ros, and need to know what files might not be included in the installation, and how to add them or edit them to clear up this error.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143236/stageroscam,-using-stage,-and-rviz/) by [udmamrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4590/udmamrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-22**:
Try to change stage_ros by just stage. The name stage_ros is for hydro

**Comment by [udmamrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4590/udmamrl/) on 2014-03-23**:
I changed my file, it ran and shut down
[Loading __name:=IGVC2013_Auto-Nav_Basic]err: unable to open world file __name:=IGVC2013_Auto-Nav_Basic : No such file or directory (/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-stage-1.6.6/debian/ros-fuerte-stage/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/worldfile.cc Load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works, thanks!

---

Originally posted by [udmamrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4590/udmamrl/) with karma: 28 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0